# how to readprocessmemory a union vars inside struct

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

Basically am trying to iterate through function address's from a running process which is a dummy program that I have created so what I do is this

```
IMAGE_THUNK_DATA first_thunk = { 0 };

if(!ReadProcessMemory(handle,process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk,&first_thunk,sizeof(first_thunk),0))
    return false;

std::cout << "Function address :" << std::hex << "0x"  << first_thunk.u1.Function << '\n';
```

Now everything you see is correct and I read it from the target process without a problem but now
when I try to print `first_thunk.u1.Function` I get an address that will land inside `MessageBoxA` function.
But I want the address of it and not an address inside that function anyways if I do this `auto address = process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk;` I get what I want which is the address of `MessageBoxA`
So I am so confused. Why doing `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` works and using the struct that I read doesn't which is my big problem regarding this question when I try to read the `sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)` I read 8 bytes which is understandable since its inside a union which shares the address space for 4 variables inside there but how would I get each variable address or access each var address or rva using `ReadProcessMemory` since its only reading 8 bytes I can't do that.

Comment: Why do you hate formatting?

Comment: @MikeCAT i don't it just confuses me how to actually get it write am trying to fix it as we speak

Comment: *"Now everything you see is correct"* - If that were true you wouldn't be asking here, would you?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you, you've got different results with `auto address` and `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` in `ReadProcessMemory`, right? Have you tried: `(PBYTE)process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk`?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT i think you missunderstood me how doing `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk;` (without reading this line from memory) can get me the address of `MessageBoxA` shouln't a struct of type `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA` be after `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ` struct?

Comment: Ok, so you've read a `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA` from `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` correctly, and as you said *its inside a union which shares the address space for 4 variables*, they have the same address and same value. which is `ForwarderString=Function=Ordinal=AddressOfData`. If you want to get the struct data when the file is loaded into memory, as my answer, use `import_desc.FirstThunk` to get `Function` or `Ordinal`, use `import_desc.OriginalFirstThunk` to get `ForwarderString` or `AddressOfData`

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT okay so i thought about something when i try to print `std::cout << "Function address : << std::hex << "0x" << first_thunk.u1.Function << '\n';  ` i get the address not of the function `MessageBoxA` but instead i get an offset inside that function (first instruction inside it) i want to get the address of `&MessageBoxA` and not just a pointer to the first instruction inside it and doing it with `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` is weird cuz sometimes it points to functions address's and sometimes it points at random place inside the executable.

Comment: Could show a minimal example of this issue, or use the sample in my answer to check if you can get the right address? BTW, if I print the `p` in my target process, the value is the same as the address I get in sample.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT okay if you try to print the address of `lpBaseAddress = (PBYTE)hModule + ImportDesc.FirstThun` without reading it from memory just print it like that it will give you the address Of &MessageBoxA but if you read that from memory it will go inside MessageBoxA and will return the address of the first instruction in memory.

Comment: According to the [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#delay-import-address-table), the delay-load helper updates `u1.Function` with the real entry points.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT thanks for trying to help but i guess i will have to figure it out by myself since its complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Which you mean is `ReadProcessMemory` with `auto address = process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` works for you but doesn't work with `process_base_address + import_desc.FirstThunk` directly, I recommend to use `(PBYTE)` Conversion.

According to your description sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA) = 8, I assume you use the x64 version.

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64 {
    union {
        ULONGLONG ForwarderString;  // PBYTE 
        ULONGLONG Function;         // PDWORD
        ULONGLONG Ordinal;
        ULONGLONG AddressOfData;    // PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME
    } u1;
} IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64;
typedef IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64 * PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA64;
```

When the highest value of `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA` is 1, it means that the function is imported in the form of a serial number, otherwise, the function is imported in the form of a function name, and it is an RVA, pointing to an `IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME` structure. We can use constant `IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG` to test whether the highest bit is 1.

The following sample work for me:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <psapi.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int i;
    HMODULE hModule;
    DWORD dwOffset, cbneeded;
    SIZE_T dwRet;
    DWORD dwPid = 8752; // PID of process to be hooked
    TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szHookModName[MAX_PATH] = { "user32.dll" };
    TCHAR szFuncName[MAX_PATH] = { "MessageBoxA" };
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER DOSHeader;
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory;
    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportDesc;
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA OrigThunkData;
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA RealThunkData;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME pImportByName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)malloc(255); //function name length;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    LPVOID lpBaseAddress;

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, dwPid);

    if (hProcess == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fail to open process!\n");
        return;
    }

    if (!EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hModule, sizeof(hModule), &cbneeded))
    {
        printf("Fail to enum process modules!\n");
        return;
    }

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, hModule, (void*)&DOSHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER), &dwRet))
    {
        printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
        return;
    }

    dwOffset = DOSHeader.e_lfanew + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER);

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)hModule + dwOffset, (void*)&OptionalHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER), &dwRet))
    {
        printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
        return;
    }
    DataDirectory = OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        dwOffset = DataDirectory.VirtualAddress + sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) * i;
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)hModule + dwOffset, (void*)&ImportDesc, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR), &dwRet))
        {
            printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
            return;
        }
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)hModule + ImportDesc.Name, (void*)szModName, MAX_PATH, &dwRet))
        {
            printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
            return;
        }
        if (stricmp(szModName, szHookModName) == 0)
            break;
        i++;
    } while (ImportDesc.Name);

    i = 0;
    do
    {
        lpBaseAddress = (PBYTE)hModule + ImportDesc.OriginalFirstThunk + sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA) * i;
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, (void*)&OrigThunkData, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA), &dwRet))
        {
            printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
            return;
        }


        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)hModule + ImportDesc.FirstThunk + sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA) * i, (void*)&RealThunkData, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA), &dwRet))
        {
            printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Function address :" << std::hex << "0x" << RealThunkData.u1.Function << '\n';

        lpBaseAddress = (PBYTE)hModule + ImportDesc.FirstThunk + sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA) * i;
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, (void*)&RealThunkData, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA), &dwRet))
        {
            printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Function address :" << std::hex << "0x" << RealThunkData.u1.Function << '\n';
        

        if ((OrigThunkData.u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG) != IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
        {
            if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)hModule + OrigThunkData.u1.AddressOfData, (void*)pImportByName, sizeof(WORD) + strlen(szFuncName) + 1, &dwRet))
            {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Fail to read memory in remote process!\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (pImportByName->Name[0] == '\0')
            {
                printf("Function not located!\n");
                break;
            }
            if (strcmpi((char*)pImportByName->Name, szFuncName) == 0)
            {
                printf("Function: %s  \n ", pImportByName->Name);
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    } while (OrigThunkData.u1.Function);

    free(pImportByName);
}
```

It should be noted that the contents pointed to by `OriginalFirstThunk` and `FirstThunk` in the PE file are exactly the same, but when the file is loaded into memory, the difference appears: the contents of `OriginalFirstThunk` will not change, but the data in `FirstThunk` will change to the entry address of the function.

target process:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    printf("child\n");
    VOID *p = (VOID*)MessageBoxA;
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"TEST","TEST",0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]